# Android: Query SQLite database once, then use retrieved data without querying again

Tags: android, sqlite, countdowntimer

I am trying to get a value from an SQLite, convert it and use it in a Countdown Timer in an Android App, but I get unexpected results. I intend to query the database only once, get the data and use it without going back to the database again.

However, every time I start the activity, the database gets queried again and I get back the same old value making the countdown to start from scratch. What am I not doing right? Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
public class PyStatus extends ListActivity {

    public pyCountDown timer;
    private long startTime = 0L;
    private final long interval = 1000;
    private TextView mDaysLeft;
    private PyDbAdapter mDbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.py_status);

        mDbHelper = new PyDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();

        mDaysLeft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.days_leftTv);

        doDataConversion(); // call this method to run the countdown timer

        mDaysLeft.setText(mDaysLeft.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime));
    }

private void doDataConversion() {
        Cursor daysLeftCursor = mDbHelper.findDaysLeft();

        if (daysLeftCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnIndex = daysLeftCursor.getColumnIndex(PyDbAdapter.COL_DAYSLEFT);
            String daysToD = daysLeftCursor.getString(columnIndex);

            long stt = Long.parseLong(daysToD);

            startTime = stt;

            timer = (pyCountDown) new pyCountDown(startTime, interval).start();
        }

    }

private class pyCountDown extends CountDownTimer {

        public pyCountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mDaysLeft.setText("Days Left: " + millisUntilFinished/(1000));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mDaysLeft.setText("Done... Go home!");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save the time when application is running using `static` variables should do the trick. They persist until their parent class gets unloaded.

```
public class PyStatus extends ListActivity {

    public pyCountDown timer;
    private long startTime = 0L;
    private final long interval = 1000;
    private TextView mDaysLeft;
    private PyDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private static cursor daysLeftCursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.py_status);

        mDbHelper = new PyDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();

        mDaysLeft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.days_leftTv);

        doDataConversion(); // call this method to run the countdown timer

        mDaysLeft.setText(mDaysLeft.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime));
    }

    private void doDataConversion() {
        if (daysLeftCursor == null)
            daysLeftCursor = mDbHelper.findDaysLeft();

        if (daysLeftCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnIndex = daysLeftCursor.getColumnIndex(PyDbAdapter.COL_DAYSLEFT);
            String daysToD = daysLeftCursor.getString(columnIndex);

            long stt = Long.parseLong(daysToD);

            startTime = stt;

            timer = (pyCountDown) new pyCountDown(startTime, interval).start();
        }

    }

    private class pyCountDown extends CountDownTimer {

        public pyCountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mDaysLeft.setText("Days Left: " + millisUntilFinished / (1000));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mDaysLeft.setText("Done... Go home!");
        }

    }
}
```

Note:
If you want to save even when the application is closed you need to save the current time back to the database when the activity pauses or stops depending on your choice. Here's a link to information about the [Activity's Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html).

Comment: Thanks, let me give it a try.

Comment: It is still behaving the same way as before. Any other better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

One wayout for your requirement which I thnk will work woud be:

Use the Hashmpa to store the datbase data, Query the database only when hashmap is empty or required data is not there in hashmap.

So your code would be first check empty hashmap and then again check for the required data present in hashmap or not....

If both the conditions fail then you query the databse else you wont query... so your query statement should be inside `if` and that if fails then access database else use only hashmap data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just need a way of persisting the data in the text view so that the countdown continues straight without having to check for anything anywhere else. The hashMap would still be a query issue and I don't think there is a way I can directly decrement the hashMap value as the timer ticks.

Comment: I would have used a constant amount of time in my _startTime_ variable but the problem is that the data is coming from a user's choice and thus varying each time the configuration changes. Is there a way to make that text persist in that text box for entire duration of the countdown?